# How do I assign value to its own key in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have below code

```
   <a-table bordered :dataSource="data" :columns="columns">
      <span slot="rate" slot-scope="rate, key">
        <b-form-input type='number' v-model="rate"></b-form-input>
      </span>
    </a-table>
```

Structure of data is as below

```
[
        {
          key: "0",
          rate: "1 ",

        },
        {
          key: "1",
          rate: "2 ",
        }
```

How do i assign the updated rate to the same key for update?

Comment: This is irrelevant to your question, but consider replacing `slot-scope` with `v-slot` as it's been [deprecated](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot-scope-deprecated).

Comment: @YomS. It does not work with v-slot.

Comment: Well, I didn't say it would. Changing to `v-slot` is just a recommendation for future updates. As for your question, please add more context.

Comment: `  v-slot can only be used on components or <template>.`. Are you suggesting to change the span to template?

Comment: It's unclear what this `rate` slot is, kept me guessing. Is that from another component? The only reference I found regarding that is this [Ant Rate component](https://www.antdv.com/components/rate/), and it doesn't look like the Table has this slot.

Comment: Rate is an amount returned from API.  I have shared sameple data in the question above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to type something inside your form and have it updated in your data array.

Assuming your data table library is doing some magic behind the scenes and takes care for the binded property (**rate**) per each row, then all you should do is **deep** watch the array of objects and track changed values via some custom code \ small library that track changed values inside an object.

To be more clear, the **watch** property of Vue is responsible to tell you that there was a change inside some property in your data.

**It won't detect the changed value.**

However, inside the detection, you should invoke that custom code \ small lib to differ the value.

I will be more then happy to edit my answer in order to help you with your code once you upload a working sample via: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue

Currently, this answer operates as a guideline.